# How to create a DStream from parquet files stored in HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming, parquet

I want to read a large number of records, stored in HDFS in parquet format, and convert them into a Spark Stream, so they can be processed in batches (written to another data-store).

Is there anyway to convert DataFrames to DStreams?

Comment: is there some reason why you wouldn't use "normal" Spark for that? Sounds like a 1-time batch operation.